# How does one restart Openshift Origin master on Centos 7?

Tags: openshift, centos7, restart, openshift-origin, systemctl

Openshift origin was installed via the `ansible playbooks`.

According to [this](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/install_config/master_node_configuration.html#master-node-config-restart-services) documentation, the correct command to restart is:

```
$ systemctl restart atomic-openshift-master-api atomic-openshift-master-controllers
```

However, this just results in:

```
Failed to restart atomic-openshift-master-api.service: Unit not found.
Failed to restart atomic-openshift-master-controllers.service: Unit not found.
```

What is the correct way to restart `openshift origin` (`okd`) after installing via `ansible` on `Centos7`?

Answer (score 7):

If you get the following error:

```
bash: master-restart: command not found
```

try:

```
/usr/local/bin/master-restart
```

Answer (score 4):

If you installed the `OKD` as `v3.10`, you should restart `master` services as follows. [0] The service is running as pod from `v3.10`, so you should use the specific command for restarting the master services, such as `api` and `controllers`

```
# master-restart api
# master-restart controllers
```

[0] [RESTARTING MASTER SERVICES](https://docs.okd.io/3.10/architecture/infrastructure_components/kubernetes_infrastructure.html#control-plane-static-pods)

Comment: Are you logged into one of the masters as root when you try this?

Comment: Where do the master-restart come from ?
On the master node : locate master-restart => no result

Comment: If you use less than v3.10 version, then you should use `systemctl` for restart. Usually the script located as `/usr/local/bin/master-restart`. And you can verify to use `which master-restart`.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, you have two alternatives:

1. Using ansible

   Use the same *inventory.ini* as you used when installing OpenShift origin.

   Assuming that you have the *inventory.ini* file and the *[openshift-ansible](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible)* repository cloned under **/home/user/**, execute the master restart [playbook](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/blob/master/playbooks/openshift-master/restart.yml):

   `ansible-playbook -i /home/user/inventory.ini /home/user/openshift-ansible/playbooks/openshift-master/restart.yml`
2. Restart the services

   To restart the services manually, the service names are **origin-master-api** and **origin-master-controllers**. Thus the command to restart them should be:

   `systemctl restart origin-master-api origin-master-controllers`

I strongly recommend using the first option.

Comment: $systemctl restart origin-master-api
Failed to restart origin-master-api.service: Unit origin-master-api.service not found.

As the cluster has been untared and started with oc cluster up, that is not suprising the command below does not work, but how then to restart ?